# Birthday Paradox Tester

Tags: clojure, simulation

I randomly decided to write a program that tests the [Birthday Problem/Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

The gist of the problem/paradox is that if you have a group of people in a room, how many people are required for there to be a 50% chance that 2 people will have the same birthday? Near 100% chance? It turns out only 23 people need to be in a room for there to be a 50% chance, and with 70 people, there's essentially a 100% chance (99.9%). This is assuming a even distribution of birthdays. This was hard for me to believe, so I decided to test it!

The main things I want critique of:

- `generate-random-birthdays` was originally much simpler. I had it defined simply as `(repeat n-birthdays (new-random-birthday rand-gen))`, but the laziness seemed to interfere with the random generator. It was returning a list of the correct size, but where every element was the same (which obviously destroyed the point of the test). A fold seemed like the obvious next tool, and it works, but it seems rather ugly for such a simple task. Is there an easier was to achieve a strict `repeat`?
- Is my use of a transient in `generate-random-birthdays` justified? I timed it with and without transients, and using them I got around a 10% speed increase. This seems somewhat significant. This is really the first time I've ever used them, so is there anything I need to watch out for that would make their use less favorable (besides a bit of code-bloat)?
- `count-matching-birthdays` has a very simple definition, but I suspect the `(count (distinct birthdays))` part is expensive. I can't profile it though as VisualVM is broken on my Surface. The simplicity of it though has me suspicious (since when is the best way ever the simplest?). Is there a more efficient way of counting the number of duplicates in a list? Really, I only need to know whether or not there are any matches, not a specific number, but in the future I may way to modify this test to actually count the number of matches.
- `(if (> (count-matching-birthdays rand-birthdays) 0)
                        (inc n-dupes)
                        n-dupes))` stinks to me. This is connected to the point above. Is there a more succinct way of saying this?
- This is more of a side question, but why when I tried using transients in `test-n-people-range` did it slow it down by a fair amount (almost as much as it sped up the other function)? Are there specific circumstances transients should be used for?
- Of course, anything else you notice.

The seemingly unrelated functions at the top were just inlined from my personal library. If they seem useless here it's because using `new-rand-gen` prevents me from needing to import the random generator, and `random-int` allows for deterministic behavior, which the standard functions are disappointingly lacking.

```
(ns bits.birthday-problem
  (:import [java.util Random]))

(defn new-rand-gen
  ([seed] (Random. seed)))

(defn random-int
  "Returns a random integer (actually a long) between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)."
  ^long [^long min ^long max ^Random rand-gen]
  (+ min (.nextInt rand-gen (- max min))))

(defn iterate-many [x repetitions iterate-f]
  (nth
    (iterate iterate-f x)
    repetitions))

(defn new-random-birthday [rand-gen]
  (random-int 0 365 rand-gen))

(defn generate-random-birthdays
  "Generates a list of random birthdays."
  [n-birthdays rand-gen]
  (persistent!
      (reduce (fn [acc _]
                (conj! acc (new-random-birthday rand-gen)))
              (transient [])
              (range n-birthdays))))

(defn count-matching-birthdays
  "Returns the number of matching birthdays in a list."
  [birthdays]
  (- (count birthdays) (count (distinct birthdays))))

(defn percentage-matching-birthdays
  "Returns the percentage of tests that contained matching birthdays for the given number of people."
  [n-tests n-people rand-gen]
  (let [n-matches (iterate-many 0 n-tests
                    (fn [n-dupes]
                      (let [rand-birthdays (generate-random-birthdays n-people rand-gen)]
                        (if (> (count-matching-birthdays rand-birthdays) 0)
                          (inc n-dupes)
                          n-dupes))))]
    (double (/ n-matches n-tests))))

(defn test-n-people-range
  "Applies percentage-matching-birthdays to a range of different numbers of people.
  Returns a 2D list in the form [[n-of-people perc-matching-birthdays]]"
  [n-tests-per min-people max-people rand-gen]
  (reduce
    (fn [acc n-people]
      (conj acc [n-people (percentage-matching-birthdays n-tests-per n-people rand-gen)]))
    []
    (range min-people (inc max-people))))
```

Example:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint
  (test-n-people-range 100000 2 365 (new-rand-gen)))
```

Produces (after 29.9 minutes!):

```
[[2 0.00285]
 [3 0.00812]
 [4 0.01773]
 [5 0.02732]
 [6 0.04091]
 [7 0.05785]
 [8 0.07359]
 [9 0.09435]
 [10 0.1169]
 [11 0.14066]
 [12 0.16749]
 [13 0.19378]
 [14 0.22449]
 [15 0.25166]
 [16 0.28343]
 [17 0.31648]
 [18 0.34677]
 [19 0.37685]
 [20 0.41249]
 [21 0.44335]
 [22 0.47167]
 [23 0.50717]
 [24 0.53855]
 [25 0.56909]
 [26 0.6001]
 [27 0.62695]
 [28 0.65704]
 [29 0.67904]
 [30 0.70723]
 [31 0.72846]
 [32 0.75329]
 [33 0.77335]
 [34 0.79474]
 [35 0.81418]
 [36 0.83126]
 [37 0.84894]
 [38 0.86519]
 [39 0.87792]
 [40 0.89141]
 [41 0.90191]
 [42 0.91346]
 [43 0.92318]
 [44 0.93354]
 [45 0.94125]
 [46 0.94852]
 [47 0.95511]
 [48 0.95993]
 [49 0.96638]
 [50 0.96969]
 [51 0.97444]
 [52 0.97813]
 [53 0.98111]
 [54 0.98373]
 [55 0.98646]
 [56 0.98826]
 [57 0.99004]
 [58 0.99134]
 [59 0.99313]
 [60 0.99443]
 [61 0.99487]
 [62 0.99618]
 [63 0.99674]
 [64 0.99709]
 [65 0.99772]
 [66 0.99793]
 [67 0.99835]
 [68 0.9987]
 [69 0.99905]
 [70 0.99925]
 [71 0.99931]
 [72 0.99941]
 [73 0.99957]
 [74 0.99956]
 [75 0.99982]
 [76 0.99983]
 [77 0.99982]
 [78 0.99986]
 [79 0.99993]
 [80 0.99992]
 [81 0.99996]
 [82 0.99996]
 [83 0.99996]
 [84 0.99995]
 [85 0.99998]
 [86 0.99998]
 [87 0.99998]
 [88 0.99999]
 [89 0.99999]
 [90 1.0]
 [91 0.99999]
 [92 0.99999]
 [93 0.99999]
 [94 0.99998]
 [95 1.0]
 [96 1.0]
 [97 1.0]
 [98 1.0]
 [99 1.0]
 [100 1.0]
 [101 1.0]
 [102 1.0]
 [103 1.0]
 [104 1.0]
 [105 1.0]
 [106 1.0]
 [107 1.0]
 [108 1.0]
 [109 1.0]
 [110 1.0]
 [111 1.0]
 [112 1.0]
 [113 1.0]
 [114 1.0]
 [115 1.0]
 [116 1.0]
 [117 1.0]
 [118 1.0]
 [119 1.0]
 [120 1.0]
 [121 1.0]
 [122 1.0]
 [123 1.0]
 [124 1.0]
 [125 1.0]
 [126 1.0]
 [127 1.0]
 [128 1.0]
 [129 1.0]
 [130 1.0]
 [131 1.0]
 [132 1.0]
 [133 1.0]
 [134 1.0]
 [135 1.0]
 [136 1.0]
 [137 1.0]
 [138 1.0]
 [139 1.0]
 [140 1.0]
 [141 1.0]
 [142 1.0]
 [143 1.0]
 [144 1.0]
 [145 1.0]
 [146 1.0]
 [147 1.0]
 [148 1.0]
 [149 1.0]
 [150 1.0]
 [151 1.0]
 [152 1.0]
 [153 1.0]
 [154 1.0]
 [155 1.0]
 [156 1.0]
 [157 1.0]
 [158 1.0]
 [159 1.0]
 [160 1.0]
 [161 1.0]
 [162 1.0]
 [163 1.0]
 [164 1.0]
 [165 1.0]
 [166 1.0]
 [167 1.0]
 [168 1.0]
 [169 1.0]
 [170 1.0]
 [171 1.0]
 [172 1.0]
 [173 1.0]
 [174 1.0]
 [175 1.0]
 [176 1.0]
 [177 1.0]
 [178 1.0]
 [179 1.0]
 [180 1.0]
 [181 1.0]
 [182 1.0]
 [183 1.0]
 [184 1.0]
 [185 1.0]
 [186 1.0]
 [187 1.0]
 [188 1.0]
 [189 1.0]
 [190 1.0]
 [191 1.0]
 [192 1.0]
 [193 1.0]
 [194 1.0]
 [195 1.0]
 [196 1.0]
 [197 1.0]
 [198 1.0]
 [199 1.0]
 [200 1.0]
 [201 1.0]
 [202 1.0]
 [203 1.0]
 [204 1.0]
 [205 1.0]
 [206 1.0]
 [207 1.0]
 [208 1.0]
 [209 1.0]
 [210 1.0]
 [211 1.0]
 [212 1.0]
 [213 1.0]
 [214 1.0]
 [215 1.0]
 [216 1.0]
 [217 1.0]
 [218 1.0]
 [219 1.0]
 [220 1.0]
 [221 1.0]
 [222 1.0]
 [223 1.0]
 [224 1.0]
 [225 1.0]
 [226 1.0]
 [227 1.0]
 [228 1.0]
 [229 1.0]
 [230 1.0]
 [231 1.0]
 [232 1.0]
 [233 1.0]
 [234 1.0]
 [235 1.0]
 [236 1.0]
 [237 1.0]
 [238 1.0]
 [239 1.0]
 [240 1.0]
 [241 1.0]
 [242 1.0]
 [243 1.0]
 [244 1.0]
 [245 1.0]
 [246 1.0]
 [247 1.0]
 [248 1.0]
 [249 1.0]
 [250 1.0]
 [251 1.0]
 [252 1.0]
 [253 1.0]
 [254 1.0]
 [255 1.0]
 [256 1.0]
 [257 1.0]
 [258 1.0]
 [259 1.0]
 [260 1.0]
 [261 1.0]
 [262 1.0]
 [263 1.0]
 [264 1.0]
 [265 1.0]
 [266 1.0]
 [267 1.0]
 [268 1.0]
 [269 1.0]
 [270 1.0]
 [271 1.0]
 [272 1.0]
 [273 1.0]
 [274 1.0]
 [275 1.0]
 [276 1.0]
 [277 1.0]
 [278 1.0]
 [279 1.0]
 [280 1.0]
 [281 1.0]
 [282 1.0]
 [283 1.0]
 [284 1.0]
 [285 1.0]
 [286 1.0]
 [287 1.0]
 [288 1.0]
 [289 1.0]
 [290 1.0]
 [291 1.0]
 [292 1.0]
 [293 1.0]
 [294 1.0]
 [295 1.0]
 [296 1.0]
 [297 1.0]
 [298 1.0]
 [299 1.0]
 [300 1.0]
 [301 1.0]
 [302 1.0]
 [303 1.0]
 [304 1.0]
 [305 1.0]
 [306 1.0]
 [307 1.0]
 [308 1.0]
 [309 1.0]
 [310 1.0]
 [311 1.0]
 [312 1.0]
 [313 1.0]
 [314 1.0]
 [315 1.0]
 [316 1.0]
 [317 1.0]
 [318 1.0]
 [319 1.0]
 [320 1.0]
 [321 1.0]
 [322 1.0]
 [323 1.0]
 [324 1.0]
 [325 1.0]
 [326 1.0]
 [327 1.0]
 [328 1.0]
 [329 1.0]
 [330 1.0]
 [331 1.0]
 [332 1.0]
 [333 1.0]
 [334 1.0]
 [335 1.0]
 [336 1.0]
 [337 1.0]
 [338 1.0]
 [339 1.0]
 [340 1.0]
 [341 1.0]
 [342 1.0]
 [343 1.0]
 [344 1.0]
 [345 1.0]
 [346 1.0]
 [347 1.0]
 [348 1.0]
 [349 1.0]
 [350 1.0]
 [351 1.0]
 [352 1.0]
 [353 1.0]
 [354 1.0]
 [355 1.0]
 [356 1.0]
 [357 1.0]
 [358 1.0]
 [359 1.0]
 [360 1.0]
 [361 1.0]
 [362 1.0]
 [363 1.0]
 [364 1.0]
 [365 1.0]]
```

Which matches the expected output almost exactly (although it reached 100% with less people than expected in this test).

---

Additions:

I've since changed `count-matching birthdays` to:

```
(defn count-matching-birthdays
  "Returns the number of matching birthdays in a list."
  [birthdays]
  (- (count birthdays) (count (into #{} birthdays))))
```

It's 70% faster! I guess just putting the birthdays into a set actually makes the most sense, in retrospect. Using transients in `test-n-people-range` now seems to in fact cause a speed increase. Not sure why, unless my timing test yesterday was botched.

---

Replacing the use of `iterate-many` with a fold gave a non-negligible speed increase. I think I'll redefine `iterate-many` in terms of a fold instead of interate/nth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify most of your functions as follows:

```
(defn random-int [min max]
  (+ min (rand-int (- max min))))

(defn new-random-birthday []
  (random-int 0 365))

(defn generate-random-birthdays [n]
  (repeatedly n new-random-birthday))

(defn percentage-matching-birthdays [n-tests n-people]
  (let [n-matches (->> #(generate-random-birthdays n-people)
                       (repeatedly n-tests)
                       (remove (partial apply distinct?))
                       count)]
    (double (/ n-matches n-tests))))

(defn test-n-people-range [n-tests-per min-people max-people]
  (mapv
   (fn [n-people]
     [n-people (percentage-matching-birthdays n-tests-per n-people)])
   (range min-people (inc max-people))))
```

I've tested this with

```
(percentage-matching-birthdays 1000 23)
;0.505
```

..., much as expected.

The above generates the random integers in native Clojure, hence can dispense with explicit reference to a Java randomiser. I've also got rid of the optimisations, which I think are premature. But the main change is to use apposite core functions wherever possible.

I think your `iterate-many` ...

```
(defn iterate-many [x n f]
  (nth (iterate f) n))
```

... is wrong. I think it ought to be ...

```
(defn iterate-many [x n f]
  (take n (iterate f x)))
```

But I haven't used or tested it.

Comment: I want my random functions to take a random generator as an argument. I like having deterministic behavior. My `iterate-many` also behaves as I'd like. I only want it to return a final value; not all the values leading up to it. I don't want it to act as `reductions`.

Comment: I'll upvote this since this is faster, but I'm not sure I really want to accept it since it disregards certain aspects of the question, and appears to give skewed results for some reason.

Comment: Also, you have `take` taking 3 parameters. I think you intended `x` to be an argument to `iterate`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've tried a few of my results against the theoretical probabilities, and they look at first sight at least as close as yours.

Comment: OK, I'll check again.

Comment: You're right. I did a 100000 test/per group run, and they're right on.

Answer (score 1):

On second thoughts ...

The problem splits into two pieces:

- generating a seeded random sequence of birthdays and
- chopping up a sequence and classifying the results.

It follows that

- The sequence of birthdays doesn't have to know what is to be done to it.
- The slicing and dicing can apply to any endless sequence of
  whatever-you-like.

This way, we avoid having to pass *mutable* seeded random number generators through the layers of function calls. We just pass the *immutable* sequences they generate (off which we take as little or as much as we like). We can test our classification reporting stuff on *any* sequences, as deterministically as we like.

To generate a seeded sequence of birthdays:

```
(defn birthday-seq [seed]
  (let [gen (Random. seed)]
    (repeatedly #(.nextInt gen 365))))
```

For example,

```
(take 10 (seeded-random-birthday-seq 1))
;(75 313 142 343 309 189 144 166 58 228)
```

This is deterministic: do it again, you get the same result.

Now for slicing a sequence and classifying the slices:

```
(defn slice-and-classify [slice-count slice-size classifier coll]
  (->> coll
       (partition slice-size)
       (take slice-count)
       (map classifier)
       frequencies))
```

For example,

```
(slice-and-classify 20 7 (comp odd? #(apply + %)) (range))
;{true 10, false 10}
```

What we want is proportions:

```
(defn normalise [m]
  (let [vs (vals m)
        sum (apply + vs)]
    (zipmap (keys m) (map #(double (/ % sum)) vs))))
```

For example,

```
(normalise {:one 1, :two 2, :three 3, :four 4})
;{:four 0.4, :three 0.3, :two 0.2, :one 0.1}
```

We could roll up `normalise` into `slice-and-classify`, but they seem clearer apart.

We've now got some useful functions that we can plug together to do the necessary. Let's just see if sample size `23` does tend to produce about half the samples with duplicates:

```
(slice-and-classify 100000 23 (partial apply distinct?) (birthday-seq 42))
;{false 50592, true 49408}
```

Yes, it does.

---

The above was put together with no thought for performance. As you've noticed, the hot spot is the `classifier` function argument to `slice-and-classify`, for which `(partial apply distinct?)` is pretty slow.

If you look at [the source code for `distinct?`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5474), you'll find it doesn't use transients, presumably because `contains?` isn't available. But `count` is available, and still works provided you remember that the transient is mutable:

```
(defn unique? [[x & xs]]
  (loop [[y & ys :as coll] xs, seen (transient #{x})]
    (or (not coll)
        (let [n (count seen) ; remember this before we mutate `seen`
              seen (conj! seen y)]
          (and (> (count seen) n)
               (recur ys seen))))))
```

This is modified to take a single collection argument, thereby dispensing with the need to `apply` it.

```
(slice-and-classify 10000 23 unique? (birthday-seq 42))
;{false 5092, true 4908}
```

It works, but - though faster than `(partial apply distinct?)` - it's not much faster than your `#(= (count (into #{} %)) (count %))` or the `#(= (count (set %)) (count %))` variant.

---

To seriously improve performance, I'd try the following:

- Generate the birthdays as an endless sequence of Java
  vectors-of-long, cut to size.
- To test for the distinctness of its elements, loop through the
  vector, accumulating a Java `BitSet`.

With appropriate type hints/casts, this should avoid a lot of boxing and unboxing.

Comment: I tried to improve the performance, as suggested. Doing so made little perceptible difference :(.